# How to get a mean of multiple column values using R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, mean

(I am a SAS programmer trying to learn R).

I have multiple numeric columns. Using `dplyr`, I want to get a mean of those multiple values per each row.  In SAS, this would be:

```
newvariable = mean(of x1, x2, x3, x4, x5);
```

I imagined it would look like this in R, but it just generates an error message.

Code:

```
time1data %>%
  mutate(newvariable = mean(of x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)) %>%
  head
```

Comment: what error message? can you also pleasae include a sample of your data? You can do that by typeing `dput(head(data))` and adding the output to your questions

Comment: also `of` is not a real thing in R

Comment: Try `time1data %>% mutate(newvariable = rowMeans(.[c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5")]))`

Comment: A base R solution could be something like: `rowMeans(time1data[,c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5")])`

Comment: Thanks, this worked:
time1data$newvar<-rowMeans(time1data[,c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x", "x6", "x7")])



I added "na.rm=TRUE" to it, which has to do with how to treat missing values and it didn't generate an error message.  Do you think this is necessary?
time1data$newvar<-rowMeans(time1data[,c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8")],na.rm=TRUE)

Comment: its almost always necessary. if false, `mean(c(1,2,3,NA)) = NA` super annoying

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# convert to a data frame if not already.
data_frame <- as.data.frame(your_data)

# These are the columns I used for testing for data with five columns
# and are to help you understand the next line of code.
colnames(dataframe) <- c("First", "Second", "Third", "Forth", "Fifth")

# tidyverse gather() via install.packages("tidyverse")
# index is the name of the "key" column, "Group_Mean" of value column
# Kept the convert = True otherwise, they become factor or strings
df.gather.col <- gather(data_frame, key="index", value="Group_Mean",
                        First, Second, Third, Forth, Fifth, 
                        convert=True)

#just prints it out.      
 df.gather.col
```

Further reading [R gather usage](https://rdrr.io/cran/tidyr/man/gather.html) and most importantly, hopes this helps.

Comment: I would suggest using the naming convention `_` for `.` to stay in line with `tidyverse` principles.

Comment: Thank you all.  This was the first time I asked a question here.  I really appreciate all of your responses.  I couldn't understand some replies and didn't know how to respond to.  Sorry, but thank you!